# MySQL Join Table Without UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Can anyone help me on how could I join two tables without merging the result into single row? Please see below query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM resorderdetails rd
 INNER JOIN resinvalidorderdetails ri
    ON rd.itemid=ri.srcitemid;
```

Let say for example I have 1 row in `resorderdetails` table with field `itemid=1` and I have 1 row in `resinvalidorderdetails` table with field `srcitemid`=1.

If we will going to execute the above query, it will return a result of single row [merging the data of two tables]

What I want to do is to have two rows as a result. The first row is the record came from `resorderdetails` and the other row is the record came from `resinvalidorderdetails` without using `UNION ALL` or `UNION`.

How could I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: What is the problem with UNION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, because you wannna have :

```
SELECT * FROM resorderdetails rd
```

and

```
select * from resinvalidorderdetails
```

There are only joins operations and UNION which you don't want to use, and the JOINS will put together or remove commons ids and UNION will do exactly what you want

Beside to display a query with 2+ tables you need something in common(even the union need same number of columns).